# Eliminating dplyr redundant function rows

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

# Example 1 -----------------------------------------------------
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(dubcyl = cyl * 2, dubcyl.avg = mean(.$dubcyl)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
#> Warning message:
#> In mean.default(.$dubcyl) :
#>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

# Example 2 -----------------------------------------------------
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(dubcyl = cyl * 2) %>% 
  mutate(dubcyl.avg = mean(.$dubcyl)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Is there a way to create my desired `dubcyl` column as shown in *example 1* without having to mutate twice as shown in *example 2*?

Comment: Why not put the second mutate inside the first? `mutate(dubcyl = mean(cyl * 2))`?

Comment: Why do you need `.$` `mutate(dubcyl = cyl * 2, dubcyl.avg = mean(dubcyl))`. If you want to `.$` use `.data$dubcyl`

Comment: I thought I was only required to use `.data` if I had previously `group_by`'d my data frame. Is that incorrect?

Comment: The `.data$` gives the full column if there is no grouping and the values for each group when grouped. iN both cases, thee unquoted column. name without the `$` wouldd work.  It can be a case when you try to pass a variable without wanting to use the `!! sym` approach i.e. `v1 ,<- "dubcyl"; mtcars %>% mutate(dubcyl = cyl * 2, dubcyl.avg = mean(.data[[v1]]))`

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a `.$` here

```
library(tibble)
librrary(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   mutate(dubcyl = cyl * 2, dubcyl.avg = mean(dubcyl)) %>% 
   as_tibble()
```